# Image has not same height as text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want the image to be the same height as the text. Regardless of how long the text is.
I do not know where my mistake is and why it does not work.
I think that float: left is a problem. I used a Clearfix. It can not be so.
Flexbox shouldn't be used in this case.

The result should look like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

html{
  font-size: 62.5%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

/* *** START: Clearfix *** */
.clearfix::after {
  content:"";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
/* *** END: Clearfix *** */


section#test1 {
  background-color: #3d3f45;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section#test1 div h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

section#test1 div p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

section#test1 p:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

section#test1 .test2 > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

section#test1 .test2 div:first-of-type {
  float:left;
  width: 70%;
}

section#test1 .test2 div:last-of-type {
  float:right;
}

section#test1 .test2 div:last-of-type img {
  height:100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="test1">

      <div>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>


      <div class="test2 clearfix">

        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet aesthetic forage tumeric kinfolk kickstarter, locavore meditation ugh. Vexillologist art party shoreditch meditation roof party. Beard ethical offal helvetica palo santo austin health goth. Hoodie venmo cold-pressed, green juice adaptogen hexagon neutra portland narwhal kale chips hashtag sriracha put a bird on it tofu. Beard banjo taiyaki readymade 90's, raclette art party irony lyft green juice humblebrag meh.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
          <p>Etsy mumblecore banh mi banjo church-key +1. Fam YOLO salvia glossier actually affogato. Keytar af vinyl, literally man bun hell of normcore taxidermy lo-fi everyday carry. Iceland pork belly unicorn, pour-over trust fund live-edge brooklyn sustainable occupy truffaut. Banh mi chartreuse small batch photo booth pok pok PBR&B blog, taxidermy locavore. Sriracha farm-to-table scenester, shabby chic before they sold out chartreuse williamsburg coloring book letterpress unicorn hoodie.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=11811719" alt="Logo">
        </div>

      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: you need the image to be same height as the text, so what about the aspect ratio of the image??

Comment: I said height:100%; and width: auto; to the image

Comment: Is it possible to transform that image in a background-image and work with background-size to cover entirely a div? Without a parent fix height, height:100% doesn't work.

Comment: @ReSedano what do you exactly mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: Sure. Something like this (resize your browser to understand the image behavior): https://jsfiddle.net/4p17Lkhb/2/

Comment: @ReSedano but the image don't scale

Comment: The image mantains its aspect ratio, scaling itself in center of the div. But you can play with background-position and/or background-size to change its behavior. Check it: https://jsfiddle.net/f89pajy5/3/. I have no other idea to help you, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the height 100% to the image parent div. I have given the class image to the image parent div and height to the test div.

HTML code

```
<section id="test1">

      <div>
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>


      <div class="test2 clearfix">

        <div class="paragraph">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet aesthetic forage tumeric kinfolk kickstarter, locavore meditation ugh. Vexillologist art party shoreditch meditation roof party. Beard ethical offal helvetica palo santo austin health goth. Hoodie venmo cold-pressed, green juice adaptogen hexagon neutra portland narwhal kale chips hashtag sriracha put a bird on it tofu. Beard banjo taiyaki readymade 90's, raclette art party irony lyft green juice humblebrag meh.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
          <p>Etsy mumblecore banh mi banjo church-key +1. Fam YOLO salvia glossier actually affogato. Keytar af vinyl, literally man bun hell of normcore taxidermy lo-fi everyday carry. Iceland pork belly unicorn, pour-over trust fund live-edge brooklyn sustainable occupy truffaut. Banh mi chartreuse small batch photo booth pok pok PBR&B blog, taxidermy locavore. Sriracha farm-to-table scenester, shabby chic before they sold out chartreuse williamsburg coloring book letterpress unicorn hoodie.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
          <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
           <p>Literally small batch poutine distillery vice, trust fund gentrify. Ramps williamsburg swag woke. Lyft viral activated charcoal williamsburg. Neutra ennui fanny pack mustache pok pok sustainable activated charcoal. Artisan biodiesel ugh messenger bag woke activated charcoal vape heirloom meditation scenester deep v pour-over organic subway tile.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=11811719" alt="Logo">
        </div>

      </div><!--/test2-->
  </section>

CSS code--

.test2{
  height:800px;
}

.image{
  height:100%;
}
```